# InfluxDB structure JMeter

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

JMeter is puting all the response data in InfluxDB. In Chronograf I can now see the performance over time, thats working fine.

The thing that I want is not comparing the performance data over time, but comparing the performance data about an software version. So I can easy see that the deployed version of today is slower than the version of last week. So more a kind of regression test.

What is the best way to do this? Can I add some extra field to the measurements in InfluxDB with the version number / branch name? Can I do something with tags? Is InfluxDB the right solution for my "problem"?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [GraphiteBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/graphite/GraphiteBackendListenerClient.html) which has `rootMetricsPrefix` field.

So you can set different `rootMetricsPrefix` value for different test runs against different software versions and this way distinguish metrics coming from different tests in a single dashboard.

References:

- [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results/)
- [JMeter – Real Time Results – InfluxDB & Grafana – Part 2 – Adding Custom Fields](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana-part-2-adding-custom-fields/)